# How to understand selection.data()

Tags: d3.js

I make a project with D3 v4. However, I have a problem understanding data binding using `selection.data()` with a key function.

```
var data = [
  {"id": 1},
  {"id": 1}
];

var nodes = d3.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d){
  return d.id;
})

console.log(nodes.enter());
```

Why does `nodes.enter().nodes().length` equal two?
Then I was try push data the same id;It is also in nodes.enter()
https://jsfiddle.net/Fboy/2jo3Lm6z/
Why does this happen?

Comment: Regarding your edit some 5 minutes ago: Have you read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40190394/4235784)? It explains what happens to duplicate items in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key function by itself does not guarantee uniqueness of your data. If you want your data to be distinctly identifiable you need to provide a suitable key function. How the data binding behaves for duplicate keys is well documented for [selection.data()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

> if multiple data have the same key, the duplicate data are put into the enter selection.

The same is documented in the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/data.js#L55-L67) when the `bindKey` strategy is applied:

```
// Compute the key for each datum.
// If there a node associated with this key, join and add it to update.
// If there is not (or the key is a duplicate), add it to enter.
for (i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i) {
  keyValue = keyPrefix + key.call(parent, data[i], i, data);
  if (node = nodeByKeyValue[keyValue]) {       // [ac]: check if node exists for this key
    update[i] = node;
    node.__data__ = data[i];
    nodeByKeyValue[keyValue] = null;           // [ac]: will put duplicate data to enter 
  } else {                                     // [ac]: no corresponding node found
    enter[i] = new EnterNode(parent, data[i]); 
  }
}
```

Comments denoted `[ac]` are mine.

Thus, if you bind an array containing two objects having the same key and no node exists matching that key, both data will be put into the enter selection.

Comment: Thansk for your answer.  but why I put it twice ,The 'enter' is two enterNode. why 'data.length()' is three?p is four?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since in D3 v4.x selections are not anymore *arrays*, but *objects* instead, this:

```
console.log(nodes.enter().length)
```

Will return `undefined`. But this:

```
console.log(nodes.enter().nodes())
```

Will return:

```
[EnterNode, EnterNode]
```

Which is an array with the 2 elements of the "enter" selection. Therefore:

```
console.log(nodes.enter().nodes().length)
```

Will return `2`.

Comment: I know this  but I want to know why nodes.enter().nodes().length is 2 ，id as  uniquely identifies,nodes.enter().nodes().length is 1 why is 2？

Comment: @Fboy the key function only identifies each individual node, it doesn't change the selection or its length.